# Programmatically check if editing session in progress for ArcGIS Pro SDK

Tags: c#, add-in, arcgis-pro-sdk

I have a C# Add-In program for ArcGIS Pro.
I would like to check if the user is currently editing, or no.

I recommend my users carefully toggle their edit sessions, following the recommendation in this link:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nQq3sgFbk8I

I would like my C# program to determine if the user is currently editing, or no.

I have tried several things, such as:

```
       private async void CheckEditSession()
    {
        // Check if an edit session is in progress
        bool editInProgress = false;

        await QueuedTask.Run(() =>
        {
            editInProgress = EditingModule.Current.EditState == EditState.Editing;
        });

        // Display appropriate message
        if (editInProgress)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Edit session in progress.");
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Edit Session NOT in progress.");
        }
    }
```

But, this syntax doesn't actually work. I'm not finding documentation to get the outcome I'm looking for.

How do I programmatically check for an active editing session in Pro?

Answer (score 0):

You can check at the map project level. Have you looked into the [HasEdits Property](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/sdk/api-reference/topic9218.html)